# Load select list dynamically from controller using getJSON MVC4 C#/Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am quite new to MVC and Jquery and I am trying to dynamically load data from a database to populate a dropdown list. Although the data is returned from the controller, it is not displayed in the dropdown. What is wrong here?

Here is my controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetReasonforLeave(int typecode)
        {
List<LeaveReason> reason_list = itlbg1.LeaveReasons.Where(f => f.LeaveType_typeCode == typecode).ToList(); 
return Json(reason_list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Here's the jquery:

```
function getreason(selecteditem) {

        sel_val = selecteditem.value;

        $.getJSON("/Leave/GetReasonforLeave", { typecode: sel_val })
            .done(function (data) {
            var options = $("#reason");
            $.each(data, function (item) {

                options.append($("<option />").val(item.reasonID).text(item.description));
            });


        });
    }
```

Comment: Try `$.each(data, function (index, item) {`

Comment: Also, unless `LeaveReason` contains only 2 properties (`reasonID` and `description`) you are sending unnecessary data across the wire - consider sending just the 2 properties you need - `var data = itlbg1.LeaveReasons.Where(f => f.LeaveType_typeCode == typecode).Select(r => new { value = r.reasonID, text = description });`

Comment: Thanks for that improvement on the controller, I tried it but `alert(data);` did not return any data. What is meant here by the index variable?

Comment: Refer [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) - the callback expects 2 arguments, `Integer indexInArray` and `Object value`

Comment: Thank you for the informative response Stephen. I'll  try to figure the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the changes Stephen requested and it worked. Here's the working code FYI. Thanks Stephen.
Jquery:

```
function getreason(selecteditem) {

        sel_val = selecteditem.value;

        $.getJSON("/Leave/GetReasonforLeave", { typecode: sel_val })
            .done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var options = $("#reason_dd");
            options.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                options.append($("<option />").val(item.value).text(item.text));

            });


        });
    }
```

Changed controller to:

```
public JsonResult GetReasonforLeave(int typecode)
        {

            var reason_list = itlbg1.LeaveReasons.Where(f => f.LeaveType_typeCode == typecode).Select(r => new { value = r.reasonID, text = r.description }); 
            return Json(reason_list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: You probably also want to include `options.empty()` to remove any existing options before you populate the new ones.

Comment: Updated the answer. You guys are just awesome.

Comment: Actually you have it wrong - your clearing the options in each iteration - `options.empty();` needs to go before the `$.each()` statement :)

Comment: Yes. I was wondering why only the first option was loading. All fixed now :)